# How do I create a list with the same number of elements as another list but have every element have the value 0?

Tags: python, list

I want a list maxIndexList in which all elements are to be equal to 0 like this

```
            maxIndex = 0
            maxIndex2 = 0
            maxIndex3 = 0
            maxIndex4 = 0
            maxIndex5 = 0
```

But I want the number of elements to be the same as the number of elements of arrivalDistanceList

```
            a = 23 + 3
            b = 5
            step = 2
            arrivalDistanceList = [meanSpeed * i for i in range(a, a + b * step, step)]
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

```
            for i in range(len(arrivalDistanceList)):
            maxIndexList = [0] + i
```

Comment: Why don't you just do `maxIndexList = [0] * len(arrivalDistanceList)`?

Comment: oh u re so right :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to python, but I think that you can do it by using

```
#assume that arrivalDistanceList=range(9)
arrivalDistanceList=range(9)
# define maxIndexList as a list 
maxIndexList=[]
# create new item in maxIndexList list containing the value 0
for i in range(len(arrivalDistanceList)):
      maxIndexList.append(0)
```

There is probably a more compact way to do it